# SwiftUI - Sheet doesn't work in Navigation View

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, navigationview, swiftui-sheet

Having issues with a NavigationView and Sheet.
I want to use not full-size sheet but bottom sheet and connect LoginView() and SignView() through sheet. At this time, frame of SignView never follow sheet.
So I tried two ways to solve.
First, LoginView: Has NavigationView out of the sheet and NavigationLink in sheet . But it didn't work.
So I put NavigationView in sheet, it works. But the height of the destination View becomes like sheet.
How can I solve the problem proper way? Thanks!

```
import SwiftUI

struct LoginView:View{
    @State var isPlus : Bool = false
    var body: some View{
        NavigationView{
            VStack(alignment:.center){
                Spacer()
                ZStack{
                    Button(action:{
                        self.isPlus = true})
                    {
                            Text("Sign up")
                                .padding(.horizontal,23)
                                .padding(20)
                                .font(.system(size: 25))
                                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                                .background(Color.blue)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                        }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $isPlus){
                        VStack{
                            NavigationLink(destination:SignView()){
                                Text("MyCard")
                                    .font(.title)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                            }
                        }
                            .presentationDetents([.height(300)])
                    }

                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you can get solution from the below code snippet.
By this way we can use sheet in the NavigationView.

```
struct LoginView: View {

    @State var isPlus : Bool = false
    @State private var showingSheet = false

    var body: some View {
           NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment:.center) {
                Spacer()
                ZStack{
                    Button(action:{
                        self.isPlus = true})
                    {
                        Text("First Sheet View")
                            .padding(.horizontal,23)
                            .padding(20)
                            .font(.system(size: 25))
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $isPlus){
                        VStack{
                            NavigationView {
                                NavigationLink(destination:SignView()){
                                    Button(action:{
                                        self.showingSheet = true})
                                    {
                                        Text("Full Sheet View")
                                            .padding(.horizontal,23)
                                            .padding(20)
                                            .font(.system(size: 25))
                                            .background(Color.blue)
                                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                            .cornerRadius(10)

                                    }
                                    .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet){
                                        Button("Close"){
                                            showingSheet = false
                                            isPlus = false
                                        }
                                        .presentationDetents([.large])
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            .presentationDetents([.medium])
                            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```